# What is the difference between AWS Billing and Cost Management and AWS cost explorer?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Hi StackOverflow community,

I need your help in understanding what is the difference between AWS Billing and Cost Management and AWS cost explorer.

I am not getting the difference.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At an initial glance without getting deep into both it can cause confusion, but I'll try to break them down below.

AWS Billing and Cost Management provides a summarised view of spending i.e. what you spent so far this month, and the predicted end of month bill, this is quite static and gives you a high level overview of spending. In addition you can configure your billing details from here. All of these features are free to use with no charge for accessing the interface.

AWS Cost explorer on the other hand is a paid service ($0.01 per query). By using cost explorer you can dig down into the finer details of expenditure, such as on a region, service, usage type or even tag based level. Using this you can identify costs by targeting your query to be specific enough to identify these charges. Additionally you can make use of hourly billing to get the most accurate upto date billing